# Proof by induction equation simplification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

I am at the end of my proof, but don't know how from the left side obtain the right.

equation: $\left[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2 + (n+1)^3 = \left[\dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right]^2$

This is what I have done so far:
\begin{align*}
& = \left(\frac{n^2 +n}{2}\right)\left(\frac{n^2 +n}{2}\right)+(n+1)^3\\
& = \left(\frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2}\right)\left(\frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2}\right)+(n+1)^3\\
& = \left(\frac{n^4}{4} + \frac{2n^3}{4} + \frac{n^2}{4}\right)+(n^3 + 3n^2+3n+1)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: I was looking for this kind of thing. thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You have (lhs) $$\Big(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\Big)^2+(n+1)^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2+4(n+1)^3}{4}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\big(n^2+4(n+1)\big)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: thanks for the Hint, but spliting the division wasn't necessary